# where is Coq aac_tactics installed?

Tags: coq, opam, coq-plugin

I was testing the AAC tactics library for rewrites modulo associativity and commutativity. According to a [Coq website](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/coq/pylons/contribs/files/AACTactics/trunk/AAC_tactics.Tutorial.html), one should:

> Depending on your installation, either modify the following two lines,
>   or add them to your .coqrc files, replacing "." with the path to the
>   aac_tactics library.

```
Add Rec LoadPath "." as AAC_tactics.
Add ML Path ".".
Require Import AAC.
Require Instances.
```

But I don't know how to find the path to the aac_tactics library, and using "." didn't work.

I installed Coq under Ubuntu 16.04 LTS along the lines of:

```
opam repo add coq-released https://coq.inria.fr/opam/released
opam install coq-mathcomp-ssreflect.1.6
opam install coq-aac-tactics.8.5.1
```

Does anyone know where to find the library location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this will work (at least for this tutorial):

```
(*
Add Rec LoadPath "." as AAC_tactics.
Add ML Path ".".
*)
Require Import AAC_tactics.AAC.
Require Import AAC_tactics.Instances.
```

Usually, OPAM stores its stuff in `~/.opam`. You can look it up with the following command in your terminal:

```
$ opam config var root
```

Then you can have multiple configurations called switches (it's mainly for keeping different version of the OCaml compiler). The root for your current switch can be found this way:

```
$ opam config var prefix
```

And the libraries for the current switch are kept in the directory which you can look up here:

```
$ opam config var lib
```

There you'll find the `AAC_tactics` subdirectory, which is the prefix we needed to add to our imports above.